# clang-tidy + VSCode: how to see command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-tidy

Is there a way to see the actual commmand line that VSCode is issuing to clang-tidy?

I am trying to figure out why clang-tidy is giving clang-diagnostic-error messages about being unable to find certain header files, though I have configured workspace settings file settings.json to with "C_Cpp.default.includePath" to include the necessary folders, and have configured settings.json to contain "C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args" entries such as "-Imy_path/to/the/files".

The build (clang and/or gcc and/or aarch64-linux-g++) all build fine with no errors. I am using the cmake extension in VSCode to generate the makefile (Ninja) and run the build.

I can't find the reason why the #include files are not being found by clang-tidy, so it seems that checking the actual command line being issued by VSCode would be a starting point for debugging this.

Thanks in advance for any help debugging this configuration issue.

Comment: Its probably better to ask this in the [vscode-cpptools discussions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions) section, most ms devs didn't really read questions in stackoverflow